# Ways to prevent traffic injection by ISP

Tags: network, vpn, injection

I live in a big brother country (Egypt, but valid to many other countries), which apparently bought Hacking team and fin fisher software since couple of years.

After reading about the very-easy ways to infect computer using traffic injection, I thought about putting openvpn on my main router; to prevent traffic injection.

But I am worried that when ISP sees that ALL my traffic is only vpn, one server and encrypted; they (ISP? police? cyber police? ...) might be **interested** to know why I am using VPN.

NOTE: There are 10 non-tech users using to this router (laptops, mobiles), installing openvpn to each one of them is really hard.

Questions are:

- Is is common that ISPs suspect people with always VPN?
- Is there any ways to prevent stream injection other than vpn?
- Can I pass http traffic over vpn and https without vpn?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: It will be hard for us to guess what your ISP might have as a policy.

Comment: I think the only opinion based question is the first one, in which I don't suspect an answer is necessary. The last two questions seem to be relevant.